# Какие есть open-source GUI проекты на JavaFX/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gui

Начал изучать JavaFX, и писать некоторые маленькие GUI приложения. Вроде все хорошо, но когда перехожу на что-то сложное в коде всегда какой-то бардак получается.

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли какие-то open-source GUI приложения написанное на JavaFX/Swing, чтобы я мог изучать и понять как пишутся гибкие приложения с возможностью расширения?

Comment: На Github посмотри

Comment: Там в основном фреймворки типа jfoenix, и просто примеры какие-то. А вот готовых приложении я там не нашел.

Comment: у Оракла много подробных руководств о том как писать приложения. но в целом таких приложений очень мало. в овсновном пишут веб приложения.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Самой известной в мире Java GUI программой является торрент клиент [Vuze](http://dev.vuze.com), к тому же он Open Source, правда он написан на [SWT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Среди приложении из open-source проектов пожалуй самым первым является JavaFX Scene Builder. Вот только на данный момент разработкой этого приложения Oracle не занимается. Им занимается [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/).

Вот репозиторий [Scene Builder](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder) на https://bitbucket.org/. Можете начинать изучения с него.

Что касается приложении на Swing, то думаю хорошим примерам будет Intellij IDEA. Оно написано на Swing фреймфорке. Вы можете найти исходники в github'е.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Разработчики Eclipse наверное сильно удивятся, если им скажут, что Eclipse IDE написан на Swing :) Он написан на SWT

Comment: @Barmaley Вы правы. Насчет IDE мне следовало просто Intellij IDEA указать